# Show all vertices and edges in Azure Cosmos data explorer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have created a graph which have different parts. In one part two vertices are connect. In other three vertices are connected together. The problem I have is that I would like the data explorer to display all the vertices and edges visually. Is there a gremlin query for this? It also seems as you traverse deeper in the graph the data explorer removes previously traversed parts which means you can never see the whole graph at any given time. Is there way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with the current implementation. It is designed to let you navigate large graphs where all the nodes can not be displayed at the same time.

You select the starting point from the list of nodes on the left side. As you click on a node in the graph to reveal its adjacent nodes and move the focus to this node, the data explorer hides the previous nodes that are further away from the new focused node to prevent showing too many nodes.

For your case, you can at best show either node clusters (by selecting a node in the cluster) but not both at the same time.

Comment: Although not a "solution" but thanks for clarifying that this isn't possible at the moment.